# What is use of slice in javascript-slice(-1)

Tags: javascript

The below code returns unexpected output(at least to me) at some point.

```
    var arr1 = "john".split('');
    var arr2 = arr1;
    var arr3 = "jones".split('');
    arr2.push(arr3);
    console.log("array 1: length=" + arr1.length + " last=" + arr1.slice(-1));
```

> //returns [j,o,n,e,s]

whereas

```
 console.log("array 1: length=" + arr1.length + " last=" + arr1.slice(-2));
```

> //returns [n,j,o,n,e,s]

what is the logic behind this output?

Comment: because array in an array....

Comment: `push` doesn't make a _flattened_ array.  The last element of that array is an array. Other elements are strings!

Comment: @Vohuman last element also array of string.

Comment: You need to ask a clear question.  What result are you trying to achieve?  What is the overall problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your array is

```
["j", "o", "h", "n", ["j", "o", "n", "e", "s"] ]
```

So when you remove the last index you have just the array

When you do two, you have the array and the letter "n"

Just do the slice on their own and look at result:

```
console.log(arr1.slice(-1))  //[Array[5]]
console.log(arr1.slice(-2))  //["n", Array[5]]
```

The reason your output looks like one array is being outputted is becuase the toString() is called when you concatenate it. .toString() just flattens the array and joins the indexes with a comma.